# Provide a mp3/ogg file in pieces to html5 audio

Tags: php, html, http, audio-streaming

I'm trying to provide a audio file through a browser using HTML5 audio tag:

```
<audio preload="auto">
    <source src="<?php echo $song->getUrl('mp3'); ?>" type="audio/mpeg">
    <source src="<?php echo $song->getUrl('ogg'); ?>" type="audio/ogg">
    Please update your browser.
</audio>
```

I need to save traffic, so I thought about sending partial content this way:

```
$contentType = ($format == 'mp3') ? 'audio/mpeg' : 'audio/ogg';
$filePath = $song->getPath($format);
$fileLength = filesize($filePath);

$start = 0;
if(isset($_SERVER['HTTP_RANGE']) && !empty($_SERVER['HTTP_RANGE'])) {
    $http_range = explode('-', substr($_SERVER['HTTP_RANGE'], strlen('bytes=')));
    $start = $http_range[0];
}

$remainingBytes = $fileLength - $start;

$length = min((512*1024), $remainingBytes);
$final = $start + $length;

header('HTTP/1.1 206 Partial Content');
header('Status: 206 Partial Content');
header('Content-Type: ' . $contentType);
header('Content-Disposition: inline;filename="listen.' . $format . '"');
header('Content-length: ' . $length);
header('Content-Transfer-Encoding: bytes');
header('Accept-Ranges: bytes');
header('Cache-Control: no-cache');
header('Content-Range: bytes ' . $start . '-' . $final . '/' . $fileLength);
echo file_get_contents($filePath, false, null, $start, $length);
```

The result of this is, in Chrome, the song being almost completely played (3.41 out of 3.47 seconds of a 9.1MB file). In firefox, the first 39 seconds played (I guess 512KB). In opera, a never-ending "loading" status.

Comment: Why do you think splitting it in pieces would save you bandwidth?  You still have the serve the whole file if you want people to play the whole file.

Comment: Sorry, I made a terrible mistake. You're completely right, I cannot save bandwidth with this idea. I meant I need to save user's time by letting them play while the song is being fully downloaded. Thanks

Comment: You just need to enable streaming then for your audio tag.  Nothing is needed server-side.

Comment: Hi @Brad, thanks for your reply. I cannot find which audio tag enables streaming. I've been seeking at [w3schools](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_audio.asp) and found nothing.

Answer (score 1):

[Per RFC2616](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec10.html#sec10.2.7), a `206 Partial Content` response is only valid in response to an HTTP range request:

> **10.2.7 206 Partial Content**
>
> The server has fulfilled the partial GET request for the resource. The request MUST have included a Range header field (section 14.35) indicating the desired range, and MAY have included an If-Range header field (section 14.27) to make the request conditional.

Your script is generating a 206 response for a request which may very well not have been for partial content (or may have been for a different range than you're returning), and this is confusing web browsers. There is, in all likelihood, no logic in most browsers to make additional requests to get the rest of your content, as this situation should never arise.

Your script is also not correctly processing Range requests either! Ranges include a length, and multiple ranges may be present in a request. Again, [see RFC2616 for details](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec14.html#sec14.16).

Comment: Hi, thanks for your reply. According to that RFC I cannot answer with a 206 code if the browser didn't request it. Do you know any way to make the HTML tag to request the song file in parts? I have a very slow server, and a 9MB song needs 2 minutes to start. I think that splitting the file, or starting playing it before it's 100% loaded is the solution. Thanks for the other warning, I will take it in mind once I'm sure this can be done.

Comment: No. Host your audio files on a faster connection, such as on Amazon S3.

Comment: I cannot believe this isn't possible. audio and video buffering exists, youtube does it and goear for example. I will investigate an alternative. Thanks

Comment: @gabrielanca, What do you think is happening when it takes 2 minutes to start playback?  It's buffering...

Comment: Hi, YouTube player, at least for me, starts playing immediately. When playing, I see a grey bar grow, so I believe that means YouTube is playing the video before it's completely downloaded... Maybe I'm wrong, but I was convinced about that...

Answer (score 0):

I think you mistakenly calculate the size of the file

```
$contentType = ($format == 'mp3') ? 'audio/mpeg' : 'audio/ogg';
$filePath = $song->getPath($format);
$fileLength = filesize($filePath);
```

**EDITED**

`$format` is file extension and not filepath
AND

```
filesize($filePath); // Do not returns file size
```

Comment: Geturl is a function of the class song that returns the absolute path to the file receiving a extension (mp3 or ogg). Im completely sure it works fine, and the size that filesize returns is ok. Thanks for your help